# RSA Encryption safety

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rsa

Im alittle confused about RSA safety.
Ive been google'ing for rsa algorithms and have found alot but they keys seems to be small numbers all the time.

This is so far the easiest algorithm i found:

```
void RSAEncDec(BYTE* pBuff, int iLen)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < iLen; i++)
    {
        pBuff[i] = (long)pow(pBuff[i], key) % modl;
    }
}
```

With a key generation algorithm:

```
rsacrypto::rsacrypto()
{
    long p1,p2; //Prime numbers
    long n = 0; //Modulus
    long phi =0; //Totient value.

    long e = 0; //Public key exponent.
    long d = 0; //Private key exponent.

    p1 = genrndprimes(100,900);
    Sleep(1000);
    p1 = genrndprimes(100,900);

    n = p1*p2;
    phi = totient(n);

    e = genrndnum(2,(phi-1));

    while(gcd(e,phi)!=1)
    {
        e = genrndnum(2,(phi-1));
    }

    d = (1/e)%phi; //Modular Multiplicative Inverse.

    privatekey = e;
    publickey = d;
    modl = n;


}
```

I am concerned about the "genrndprimes(100,900)", 100 between 900 is a small numbers while i learned the key sizes need to be above 512bits, its way above 900.
Am i getting something wrong here?

Thanks alot.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is im concerned about the small number and im asking if this is safe.

Comment: "key sizes need to be above 512 bits" -- Obviously not. `900` is represented in 10 bits.

Comment: Using pow and then mod does not work at all, unless it is evaluated with bigints, in that case it will just take a ridiculous amount of time. You really have to use proper modular exponentiation, there is no way around it.

Comment: the code looks to me more like prototype-code. It shows, how the algorithm works, but for real-world usage, other data types than `long` should probably be used what offer more bits.

Comment: I need to implement it in C and so far i havent found any possibility to store an integer above 512 bits.

Answer (score 1):

That is not safe at all and can be brute-forced quite fast. It would take at most 900 divisions to find the private key from the public key (assuming `genrndprimes` takes actual min and max values instead number of bits). So this would take less than a second.

You need to either write your own multiple precision code or simply use existing ones like GMP. Then you could represent big integers. Today a good starting value for *n* is a 2048-bit integer.

Furthermore a modular multiplicative inverse is not an actual division operation, because there cannot be any fractions. Everything must be done in modular arithmetic. The modular multiplicative inverse requires for example the use of the extended euclidean algorithm to find it.

But to make RSA actually usable in the real-world, you would also need to implement a padding scheme such as PKCS#1 v2.0 (OAEP).

Then you need to look into hybrid encryption if you want to encrypt data that is bigger than *n* (the padding must be also accounted for). In this case you would generate a random AES key, encrypt your data with AES and then encrypt the generated AES key with RSA, because AES keys are small enough to be encrypted.

After you've done all that, you will find that your code has bugs and is vulnerable to various side-channel attacks. You will use your favorite search engine to find an existing widely known and tested library that does all this for your, because **never roll your own crypto**.